# NodeJs running in command line shows "Aborted"

Tags: python, node.js

I am using an Amazon EC2 instance using CentOs 5.4. I installed nodejs in different servers that follow the same architecture. In the current server I installed nodejs by following the below steps.

**Installing Python**

```
yum install gcc zlib-devel python-setuptools readline-devel
cd /usr/src
wget http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.5/Python-2.7.5.tgz
tar -xzf Python-2.7.5.tgz
cd Python-2.7.5
./configure
make altinstall
python2.7 -V
```

Installing NODEJS

```
sudo yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
sudo yum install openssl-devel
cd /usr/local/
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz
tar zxvf node-latest.tar.gz
cd node-v0.10.34
PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
export PYTHON
set | grep PYTHON
python2.7 configure && make && make install
node --version
```

But the issue is, when ever I run the "node" command I see the following image.
[image]

I am not sure what has happened and how to debug it? Everything seems to be installed properly.

EDIT #1

From nodejs IRC @fullstack suggested to run "strace -f /usr/local/bin/node" - The result of this is : https://gist.github.com/aneek/0ef3d9fe1a6521fdee6a

EDIT#2
As per @fullstack's suggestion instead of using "python2.7 configure && make && make install" I tried to install with "./configure && make && make install". But error occurred (That's why I used Python2.7) 
[image]

Please suggest. I am stuck very bad :-(

Comment: I wonder if running a `yum update` to update your system prior to trying to installing Node.js would help.

Comment: Did this but no success. Please have a look at the gist. There are SIGABRT (Aborted) @ 0 (0) signals.

Answer (score 0):

**Install with EPEL**

```
wget http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
yum install -y nodejs
```

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#enterprise-linux-and-fedora

Comment: Thanks for the information but the result is the same. Result of debug https://gist.github.com/aneek/7d44ef04b7531654008d